# ReplicationFactor vs replicas in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Can we have the ReplicationFactor to 1 and no. of replicas to 3 ?

```
[user@master01 kafka]$ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test
Topic:test      PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
    Topic: test     Partition: 0    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
```

As I understand, if ReplicationFactor is n, Replicas can be <=n.
Can someone help me understand the following scenario ? as the ReplicationFactor is set 1, where as Kafka show no. of Replicas as 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ReplicationFactor` tells how many replicas there are.

`Replicas` lists the broker id of all the replicas.

In your example, `ReplicationFactor` is 1 and this single replica is hosted on broker 3. It works the same way for `Leader` and `Isr`. So broker 3 is the leader for the partition and is also the in-sync replica (Isr).

---

In case you had 2 as the ReplicationFactor, you could see something like:

```
[user@master01 kafka]$ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test
Topic:test      PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:2    Configs:
Topic: test     Partition: 0    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,1     Isr: 3,1
```

Now broker 3 is still the leader for the partition, but there are two replicas and two Isr (broker 3 and 1)